# Customize ONBUILD environment in a dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am slightly modifying [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/682708e7866caccd3f476f1d30ca60c0851249e1/3.5/onbuild/Dockerfile) to support my specific usecase: I need to specify my own `PyPi` server, where we are publishing our internal libraries. This can normally be achieved by specifying a `pip.conf` file, or by passing command line options to `pip`.

I am trying with this:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/

# 1st try: set the env variable and use it implicitely. Does not work!
# ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE pip.conf
# ONBUILD RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# 2nd try: set once the env variable, just for this command. Does not work!
# ONBUILD RUN PIP_CONFIG_FILE=pip.conf pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# 3rd try: directly configure pip. Works, but these values should not be set in the Dockerfile!
ONBUILD RUN pip install --index-url http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyyy --trusted-host xx.xx.xx.xx --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app
```

My `pip.conf` is very simple, and works when used outside `Docker`:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyyy
trusted-host = xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Links:

- `Dockerfile`'s ENV is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env)
- `pip` configuration is documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#configuration)

I have the following questions:

- Why is `ENV` not working?
- Why is explicit setup of the variable in a `RUN` command not working?
- Are those problems with `ONBUILD`, or maybe `RUN`?

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same problem and I managed to fix it adding this to the Dockerfile:

```
COPY pip.conf pip.conf
ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE pip.conf
RUN pip install <my_package_name>
```

The pip.conf file has the next structure:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = https://pypi.org/simple
trusted-host = pypi.org
               <my_server_page>
extra-index-url = https://xxxx:yyyy@<my_server_page>:<package_location>
```

This is the only way I found for Docker to find the package from the pypi server. I hope this solution is general and helps other people having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ONBUILD` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/onbuild)  adds to the image a trigger instruction to be executed at a later time, when the image is used as the base for another build.

[From the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/environment-replacement):

> Prior to 1.4, `ONBUILD` instructions did NOT support environment variable, even when combined with any of the instructions listed above.

With a docker 1.4+, try (as illustrated in [issue 15025](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15025#issuecomment-125260682))

```
ONBUILD ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE pip.conf
```

Comment: Good idea, but does not seem to work :(. My docker is `Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9`

Comment: I build the image using my dockerfile, which builds on top of the dockerfile which I have pasted, with your modification included, executing the `ONBUILDs` . My custom library is not found by pip, which is an indication that the pip configuration has not been properly read, which means that the env `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` is not set.

Comment: OK. Can you try a simple RUN echo ${yourVariable}, to see if the ENV is there?

Comment: Formatting is wrong in this comment, but the variable is indeed set: `Step 2 : RUN echo ${PIP_CONFIG_FILE}
 ---> Running in a5fc69f16f32
pip.conf`

Comment: Are those env variables marked for export? Should `pip` see that? It seems it does not.

Comment: If the echo does see the variable, pip should too, except it is called by ONBUID RUN.

Comment: Could you try an `ONBUILD RUN echo ${PIP_CONFIG_FILE}`?

Comment: @Roelant Not sure: you can leave a comment below the question, that will notify the OP.