# Python can't find the file pip.conf

Tags: python, pip

I can't find the file `pip.conf` in the path `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`  or the path `~/pip/pip.conf`. My version of pip is 8.1.2

Answer (score 82):

Use the pip to retrieve its location, here is the trick!

```
python3 -m pip config debug
```

It will list global and local env, If it set or otherwise.

Comment: Damn, this is magic ✨

Answer (score 56):

As stated in the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/), the default locations for Linux are:

- per-user: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`
- global: `/etc/pip.conf`

Comment: Beware! pip 20.0 (used in Ubuntu 20.04) has a bug, where it doesn't read /etc/pip.conf, but only /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf. This bug was fixed in pip 20.1, but the fix is currently not available in the pip package for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: it's worth noticing in those same docs that there is a third option to have a per-virtualenv configuration at `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`.

Comment: @EnnoGröper Do you know if there is an Ubuntu bug report for this?  I can't seem to find one.

Comment: What about per venv? where is the pip conf of the current venv?

Answer (score 25):

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

If you do not have the pip.conf by default, create it on your desired directory and do the export.

```
export PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/pip.conf
```

Comment: Remember, no spaces --> `export PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/pip.conf`

Answer (score 11):

Another solution not found in any of the answers about finding the `pip.conf` files currently used by pip:

```sh
pip config list
```

if no file is described you should follow most of the other answers and just create it on your own

Answer (score 9):

Before creating pip.conf I would rather check with the following command before creating one

```
find . -name 'pip.conf'
```

For me it was under home directory as

> ./Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf

Comment: I've found it in `/home/$user_name/.config/pip/pip.conf` using your command. I'm running a Linux machine.

Answer (score 6):

just create it.`~/pip/pip.conf`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work, I have an import error

Comment: So I added this lines to the config file  [global]
index-url = https://(website link) and I have error ImportError: No module named (from my site )

Comment: ~/.pip/pip.conf

Comment: As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969159/1331407 the path should be `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`

Answer (score 5):

I am using WSL ubuntu on win10, with only official python3-pip, and cannot find any pip.conf.

I just create `~/.pip/pip.conf`, and then it speeds up my `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`!

Comment: that's the simplest solution that works in `Dockerfile` too.

Comment: this answer also helps with using `pip.conf` in a `Dockerfile` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180964/customize-onbuild-environment-in-a-dockerfile

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file), it could be located in a multitude of places.

In terms of flexibility, I say the section about installing it on virtual environments is probably the most flexible IMO.

If you use a virtual environment for your python projects, then it may be desirable to have your `pip.conf` inside the virtual environment, than to have it sitting in your home directory.

The reason for this is simple. Say for example you have special projects that require specific `pip.conf` setup and you don't want to put the configurations for these projects in the `pip.conf` in your home directory or the global one, then you might find it makes life easier to create a dummy environment where this configuration lives and simply copy that environment for each new "secret" project.

---

#### Virtualenvwrapper

I will propose a simple way to achieve this with [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/path/to/python _python_project_base
cp ~/my_secret_pip.conf $VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf
```

There, that was easy.

What this allows you to do is that when next you want to create a new project, instead of using `mkvirtualenv`, you simply do:

```
cpvirtualenv _python_project_base new_virtual_env_name
setvirtualenvproject new_virtual_env_name /path/to/project_folder
```

And voila, the same `pip.conf` follows you everywhere, and you don't have to worry about polluting your other config files outside the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

copy your config file to /etc/pip.conf

this will make it apply for every user

There is a chance that your local user doesn't have read permissions on your pip.conf.

sudo chmod 644 /etc/pip.conf

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, it can be found at `%AppData%\Roaming\pip\pip.ini` (pip version 20.0.2)

Here are some other helpful answers for Windows users: [Python - cant find pip.ini or pip.conf in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28278207/1270000)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I was trying to install a venv on my allocation on a compute cluster system. What worked for me was to do the following before creating the venv.

```
unset PIP_CONFIG_FILE
```